# Unable to import numpy library in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

**I have installed python 3.6 and through pip added numpy module, but getting below error while trying to import the library. Kindly help here:**

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\as338011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in
<module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\as338011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <mod
ule>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\as338011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <m
odule>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\as338011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <m
odule>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\as338011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in
 <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\as338011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in
<module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling then re-installing numpy?

Comment: I tried reinstalling through pip multiple times , while trying with pip3 i am getting following error:

'PS E:\Machine Leaning classifier> python pip3 install numpy
C:\Users\as338011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe: can't open file 'pip3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Answer (score 0):

As your terminal suggests, you may have installed the incorrect version of numpy. If you're using python 3, you'll want to do pip3 install numpy rather than using normal (python 2.7) pip. Either way, you should try reinstalling numpy, or if that still doesn't work you can build it from source.
This is based on the fact that the problem seems to be with the numpy package rather than your system itself.

Comment: Hi Cary,
I tried reinstalling through pip multiple times , while trying with pip3 i am getting following error:

PS E:\Machine Leaning classifier> python pip3 install numpy
C:\Users\as338011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe: can't open file 'pip3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like you are missing pip3. You'll need to install that first.